# using footcite inside an image label

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

Im currently trying to implement footcites into my document

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, citestyle=reading ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{figure}       

\addbibresource{Bibliografia.bib}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[H]
            \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth]{Tesis/Imagenes/AC1.jpg}
        \captionof{figure}{ Gráfica de tensión \footcite{AC} }
        \label{Resistiva}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Where the content of my bib file is

```
@article{Linear,
    author    = {{Bob T. Smith}},
    date      = "2008",
    title     = " Linear circuit design handbook Newnes ISBN 0750687037 Instruments",
    url       = "http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuito_lineal"
}

@article{AC,
    author    ={{AllAboutCircuits}},
    date      = "2015",
    title     = "Introducción a Teoría de C.A.",
    url       = "http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-11/power-resistive-reactive-ac-circuits/"
}
```

However Im getting this

[image]

As you can see theres 2 footcites one from my text and another from my label, this shouldnt look like this but only one at the bottom

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. At the moment, I cannot reproduce your issue here

Comment: Thanks for editing, but it's still not minimal. `\footcite` needs `biblatex` package -- there is no such package loaded in your document

Comment: There is still `\addbibresource` and `\usepackage{graphicx}` missing ;-) And if you use `\footcite{}` in `\caption`, you should use it `\caption[caption for toc]{.... \footcite{AC}}`, otherwise there would be a footnote in your list of figures. But still, after all of this, I don't get what you report. I still have only one citation, at the foot of the page. Do you have a minipage around your `figure` environment?

Comment: damn im sorry im learning on the go, im on it

Comment: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`  and `\usepackage{caption}` would help ;-) But since you are using a figure environment already, there is no need to use `\captionof`. `\caption` is sufficient here

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: Getting moewe's attention by adding the `biblatex` tag. I cannot reproduce the issue. Might be a candidate for closing as unclear.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with `biblatex` it's a simple fact that you can't use `\footnote` in floating environments without special handling.